# Separar arreglo y unirlo con valores especificos

Tags: php, array

estoy tratando de obtener un arreglo unico apartir de 3 arreglos:

```
[catalogo_c_nacional] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 12
    )

[porcentaje] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10
        [1] => 60
    )

[monto] => Array
    (
        [0] => 200
        [1] => 400
    )
```

La cantidad de elementos es dinamica para los 3 arreglos, sin embargo los 3 siempre tendran el mismo numero de elementos, por la cual qusiera unir los arreglos en un arreglo de la siguiente manera:

```
Array = (
  0 => 
     (
     0=> 1,
     1=> 10,
     2=> 200
     ),
 1=> 
    (
    0=> 12,
    1=> 60,
    2=> 400
    )
)
```

Como pueden ver estoy uniendo las posiciones que estan en 0, despues todas las posiciones que estan en 1, etc, como podria lograrlo?, muchas grcias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Si todos son de la misma longitud, puedes usar [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), el cual requiere un *callable*, pero este puede ser `null`:

```php
$result = array_map(null, $catalogo_c_nacional, $porcentaje, $monto);
var_export($result);
```

La salida será:

```
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 10,
    2 => 200,
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    0 => 12,
    1 => 60,
    2 => 400,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Si, como dices, los tres arrays tienen siempre el mismo número de elementos, puedes construir el array final a partir de la lectura de uno de ellos.

Quizá esta sea la forma más natural y menos costosa de hacerlo<sup>1</sup>.

Por ejemplo:

```
$catalogo=array(1,12);
$porcentaje=array(10,60);
$monto = array(200,400);
$mData=array();
foreach($catalogo as $k=>$v){
    $mData[]=array($v,$porcentaje[$k] ?? null,$monto[$k] ?? null);
}
var_dump($mData);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(10)
    [2]=>
    int(200)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(12)
    [1]=>
    int(60)
    [2]=>
    int(400)
  }
}
```

He puesto fusión de null, por si acaso. Si alguno de los arrays no tuviera valores en una determinada posición, se creará de todos modos una entrada con valor `null`, eso lo puedes cambiar por `0`, por `false` o por lo que quieras.

Si tienes dudas, pregunta en comentarios. **Soy humano, no soy una IA.**

---

#### Notas

1. Con respecto al rendimiento de `foreach` ver [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18144782/5587982) y sus respuestas.